# Limiting File Size when Resizing with GDI+

Tags: c#, image, graphics, resize, gdi

I am resizing uploaded images as follows:

```
var bmPhoto = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);

using (var grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto))
{
  grPhoto.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighSpeed;
  grPhoto.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
  grPhoto.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.Low;
  grPhoto.DrawImage(sourceImage, new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                        new Rectangle(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

How can I limit the resulting file size so that it is no bigger than, say, 3KB? I am uploading a 1024x768 JPG which is 768KB. When resizing to 100x100 with the above code, I can't get it any smaller than 12KB.

Comment: An odd requirement, have you tried resizing it using another tool to see if 3KB is achievable at 100x100 or do you just need to make it smaller, say 64x64?

Answer (score 1):

The **resize** code isn't what you need to be looking at.  Take a look at the jpeg compression level when you are doing your **Bitmap.Save()**.

3kb is completely doable with a 100x100 image.  If you are getting 12kb, you are most likely saving the jpeg with the highest quality jpeg compression.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx) is an MSDN article about how to set the compression level when saving the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to play with the [quality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.quality.aspx) property, but there is a way to know whats the resulting image size. You can also try to save the file as png, which works better for non photo images (graphics)

Comment: I don't think I can lower the quality any more without dropping to 8-bit. Unfortunately, these are photos.

Comment: @Mark Richman, if you can't lower the quality any further then the question becomes moot. 12KB is the best you are going to do at that quality level and size.